# Memory Leak While doing encryption decryption of large audio/video/html files using Java AES

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I got a task to perform encryption and decryption of some large amount of files which are consisting of Audio,Video,and some html,swf files. And for this the code I am using works fine in my system. But when I am trying to execute the same code on server using java RMI it throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` Java heap space.

Please suggest your views how to solve this memory leak issue.

Following is the code that I am using:

```
public static void performEncryption(String baseFolderLocation) 
{       
    String key = "This is a secret";

    System.out.println("Started Doing Encrypting...");
    List<File> filenames = getAllfilesInFolder(baseFolderLocation, new ArrayList<File>());
    int processedFilesCount = 0;

    for (File file : filenames) {
        try {

            Crypto.fileProcessor(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, file.getAbsoluteFile(), file.getAbsoluteFile());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        processedFilesCount++;
    }

    System.out.println("Ended Encrypting...");
}

static void fileProcessor(int cipherMode, String key, File inputFile, File outputFile) {
    try {
        Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey);

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
        inputStream.read(inputBytes);

        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static List<File> getAllfilesInFolder(String directoryName, ArrayList<File> files) {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);

    // get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : fList) 
    {
        if (file.isFile()) 
        {
            files.add(file);
        }
        else if (file.isDirectory()) 
        {
            getAllfilesInFolder(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
        }
    }

    return files;
}
```

Comment: How large are the files you are encrypting?  Storing files larger than ~2.147 GB will produce this error.

Comment: Your input and output files seems to be equal...

Comment: Crypto.fileProcessor(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, file.getAbsoluteFile(), file.getAbsoluteFile());

Comment: Don't read in the whole file all at once, use a `CipherOutputStream` and pipe it to your `InputStream`.

Comment: The file size is around within 200-300 MB @LukePark

Comment: Yes sir, on same file i am performing encryption and decryption on same location. @c69

Comment: I am reading the complete directory then i am performing encryption/decryption for each individual file in that ROOT folder. This code working sir if i run as a sample application but while calling this method from server using java RMI, it throws OutOfMemory error @piet.t

Comment: sir can you provide some sample about usage of CipherOutputStream to do encryption/decryption on same content in same location @piet.t

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to increase java heap memory of your server using -Xmx option?

Comment: Already done by increasing heap memory but same result @Rahul B.